# How to compile program that uses boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019, boost-filesystem

I'm trying to compile a sample program that uses boost::filesystem:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path full_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());
    std::cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << std::endl;
}
```

I've downloaded and compiled boost 1_72, added `my_path_to_boost` to include directories and `my_path_to_boost\stage\lib` to include lib directories

When I try to compile the program, I'm getting following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib' current-path    D:\My Projects\filesystem\current-path\LINK 1
```

I have verified that `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib` is located in `my_path_to_boost\stage\lib`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019

What am I missing? Is there any way I can see where VS is looking for the file?

Comment: `libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib` and `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib` filenames are different

Comment: wow. I totolly missed that!